# Can I steam Kao Fu in a steam oven?

Tags: steaming, seitan

I recently made kao fu from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwFhvy3ug3M. From what I can tell it's just seitan with added yeast for the rise

I steamed it in the largest sauce pan I have, and it was successful but it was way too big for the pan and kept pushing up against the pan lid every couple of minutes (when it got too big I'd take the lid off and let it settle back down a bit)

I've got an AEG BES355010M steam oven, and though I've never used the steam functionality I was wondering if it would be useful for a task like this? I'm unsure if using it as a steam oven would serve the same purpose, or if it'll be more oven and less steam

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Apparently this was too specialized a question for our community.  My only suggestion is "try it and see".